# What is the status of arts at museums?

Tags: intellectual-property

I'm in more interest of intellectual property stuff. For example if I'd like to take a picture of some masterpiece painting in the Louvre museum, can I spread thic pic or even sell via different photostocks. And can I take a pics with 360 cameras in museum for commercial purposes? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing very special about art *being in a museum*.

You have two major problems:

Firstly, art is copyright.  According to the Berne convention, copyright persists at least 50 years after the artist's death, but it can be longer (70 years in the US and the EU).  So for example, Picasso's works won't come out of copyright for another 24 years in the US/EU.  This means you need a license *from the copyright holder* to take a photograph.  Note that the copyright holder is probably *not* the museum, but in this case Picasso's estate.

Of course, if you are trying to take a photograph of a work by a Renaissance master it will be well out of copyright.

Secondly, museums are private spaces.  As such they can impose any conditions they like before allowing entry. Almost all museums impose a condition "no commercial photography without a permit" (or sometimes even a blanket "no photography without a permit").

In the specific case of the Louvre, their [website](https://www.louvre.fr/en/how-use-louvre/visitor-regulations) says:

> Artworks in the permanent collection exhibition rooms may be photographed or filmed for private use by the operator. The use of flash and other lighting equipment is prohibited. Photography and filming is strictly prohibited in the temporary exhibition rooms.
>   Filming and photography of installations and technical equipment is also strictly prohibited.